# Objective-C Enum if-statement

Tags: objective-c, if-statement, enums

I am trying to work with enums so I've created a simple grade calculator:

```
    enum grades {
A,
B,
C,
D,
F

};

enum grades gradeSimplifier(int numericGrade){
if (numericGrade>100) {
    NSLog(@"Error");
    return 0;
}
if(numericGrade>=90 && numericGrade<=100){
    return enum grades.A;

}
if(numericGrade>=80 && numericGrade <90){
    enum grades = B
    return grades grades.B;
        }

if(numericGrade >= 70 && numericGrade < 80) {
    enum grades = C
    return grades grades.C;
}

if (numericGrade>=60 && numericGrade <70) {
    return grades grades.D;
}

else {
    return  grades grades.F;
}
}
```

Basically I want the code to take an integer value and convert it to a letter grade. I am struggling with the syntax of how to make the if statements return an enum value.

Also, I'm aware that I could have used a switch so no need to comment on that.

Thanks!

Comment: The argument to `return` is just an expression. You access an `enum` in a `return` statement the same way you access it in any other expression.

Comment: The enum value `A` will have a value of `0`. So your check for an error returns the same value as `A`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several problems here. First, the modern way of declaring `enum`s in objective-C is with [`NS_ENUM`](http://nshipster.com/ns_enum-ns_options/). So you should declare your enum like this:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, Grade) {
    A, B, C, D, F
}
```

Second, you may want to consider renaming your enum values. They basically become global constants, and there is no namespacing in Objective-C. So usually people prefix their enum values with the name of the enum. (Also, people use three-letter prefixes in the place of namespaces, but that's a separate issue.) I would think something like this would be better:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, Grade) {
    GradeA, GradeB, GradeC, GradeD, GradeF
};
```

Then, you can declare your function like this, using the newly-declared enum type:

```
Grade getLetterGradeFromNumeric(int numericGrade) {
    if (numericGrade >= 90) return GradeA;
    else if (numericGrade >= 80) return GradeB;
    else if (numericGrade >= 70) return GradeC;
   // ... etc. 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Is that what you want?

```
typedef enum : NSUInteger {
    GradeError = 0,
    GradeA,
    GradeB,
    GradeC,
    GradeD,
    GradeF
} Grade;


-(Grade)TheGrade:(int)numericGrade
{
    if (numericGrade>100) {
        NSLog(@"Error");
        return GradeError;
    }

    if(numericGrade>=90 && numericGrade<=100){
        return GradeA;
    }
    //....
}
```

Comment: What is `GradeError`?

Comment: And use `if/else` statements to make it MUCH simpler.